# Add custom attributes whenever div content changes

Tags: javascript

I have an empty div (id="parent") inside which a 3rd party widget renders some content (say div, and anchor tags). Now, I need to add some custom attributes to the div and anchor tags whenever they are rendered by the widget.

So I have a MutationObserver as below:

```
var parent = document.getElementById("parent");
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations){
    functionToAddCustomAttributes();
});

observer.observe(parent, {
  subtree: true,
  childList: true
});
```

Inside functionToAddCustomAttributes(), I have code to add the attributes. My question is, if I add the attributes, shouldn't it call the MutationObserver again, since I'm updating the child of #parent? Shouldn't it cause an infinite loop? It doesn't look like it is happening in my code, so I just want to make sure this is the right way to do it.

If not, is there any other way to add the attributes whenever the widget renders the content?

Comment: seems that the code is using some implementation of event subscription pattern (like https://github.com/mroderick/PubSubJS or so, but not DOM events), in this case I see the follwing explanation why there's no loop : 1) code that renders widget does publish event - "done" which is processed by MutationObserver - because MutationObserver is subscribed on it; 2) while doing functionToAddCustomAttributes this publish event is not triggered so nothing happens => no loop

Answer (score 0):

Listen on onDomSubTreeModified event for the parent div instead of MutationObserver. In the callback add your custom attributes and use return false; to be on safe side.

Comment: I thought onDomSubTreeModified was very inefficient, such as firing an event for every child that was modified, and that MutationObserver overcomes such inefficiencies.

Comment: I actually mean to add a eventlistener only to the intended element i.e.., #parent.

Answer (score 0):

After the code to add attributes, try this:

```
$('#parent').find('#someChild').attr('name', 'value');
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand. How would that help?

Comment: When functionToAddCustomAttributes() finishes rendering the tags, you can use the #parent to find #child and add custom attributes.